# Google place picker closes immediately after launch

Tags: android, google-places-api

This is a problem that I've been stuck for weeks, but still, I can't solve it. My friend's google place picker worked, but not mine (even though we have the same code).

But once in 20-30 tries, it opens the UI lets me have a look at nearby places around my location (but that's a very very rare case).

I've done everything I possibly could.

1) I've enabled **Google Places API for Android** and generated my API key. I've also added my **SHA-1** certificate fingerprint and **package name**.

2)I've imported everything related to google play services that I could in gradle.

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

3)I've also given my API key inside of **meta-data** in my **application tag** in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_place_api" />
</application>
```

4)I've copied the exact code that I got from Place-picker documentation site https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker

```
 PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(maps.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (
            GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (
            GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

5)I've even enabled **billing** for my project, where Google charged me Re 1.

This is very important for my project, so please someone help me. I beg of you.

**Edit:** I'm getting some kind of error in my logcat too:

```
     Place Picker closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED
 the Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    2019-05-12 08:07:57.106 2818-3899/? E/Volley: [171] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/placePicker?key=AIzaSyCz-bC6nazJur-gHEgVoZMujFDyVvs2n9M
    2019-05-12 08:07:57.110 2818-20254/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
    2019-05-12 08:07:57.112 2818-20254/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=PlacePickerQuota
```

**EDIT#2**: Is there any solution to this? Please answer me.

Comment: your app closes immediately after launch? you mean crashed?

Comment: It doesn't show any error, it just closes the moment it opens up.

Comment: Alright, I will post my own implementation of Google place picker.

Comment: My implementation is basically the same thing as yours...have you checked your error log if any?

Comment: No error in my log cat.

Comment: There is error, you're not just paying attention

Comment: I can see the error already

Comment: Yes, I am getting an error that Places API has not been enabled, but I've enabled Places SDK for Android.

Comment: Mine is working fine after enabling place API

Comment: perhaps you're enabling it for the wrong project...

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to have enabled place API, below is the link to the steps to get that done.
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en

if you check your logcat well enough, maybe by selecting the types of log you want to see, you can select Error instead of verbose, then you will see the error like below

```
E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
```

Comment: I have enabled Places API for Android. I've double checked it.

Comment: That's weird, I will disable mine to confirm this

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to the deprecated version of Places SDK for Android. You have the following statement in gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

This refers to the Google Play version of Places SDK, that was deprecared. In order to use new static library of Places SDK the gradle should use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

Please double check all steps mentioned in the documentation of new library to be sure that you migrated to new version correctly:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start

I hope this helps!

Comment: So should I delete `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'` from my `build.gradle`?

Comment: I've tried  putting `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'` inside my dependencies. But still the place picker closes.

Comment: Did you follow all steps from the documentation?

Comment: Yes if I put `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'` , then I can't import Place picker. But I need placepicker in my app.